# Sort List except one entry with LINQ, to be at the last

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to order a List of strings but one string in the list should always be at the last and not sorted. What is the easiest way to do this with LINQ?

```
//should be ordered in:  a,b,u,z, last:
List<string> l = {"z","u","last","b","a"};
```

There is no append method or something in LINQ, is there?

Comment: what do you mean by "one string in the list should always be at the last and not sorted". Please share some more examples.

Comment: @AmitVerma this example: //should be ordered in:  a,b,u,z, last:
List<string> l = {"z","u","last","b","a"};

Comment: but how will you decide which string should be at last ? There must be some deciding criteria.

Comment: @AmitVerma the deciding criteria is "last" value, by value.

Comment: it means "last" word will always be there in list and you just want to append at last of sorted string. RIght ??

Comment: @AmitVerma yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `.Concat()` to add the string that you desire at the end or use `.OrderBy()` to place your string at the end while leaving all others in the front and use `.ThenBy()` afterwards to sort the items. `.ThenBy()` will apply when you the previous orderings provide groups of items that are considered equal.

```
var list = new List<string> { "z", "u", "last", "b", "a" };
var result = list
    .OrderBy(item => item == "last" ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(item => item);
```

Or in place sort

```
var list = new List<string> { "z", "u", "last", "b", "a" };
list.Sort((left, right) => left == "last" ? 1 : right == "last" ? -1 : string.Compare(left, right));
```

Using `.Concat()`

```
var list = new List<string> { "z", "u", "last", "b", "a" };
var result = list
    .Where(item => item != "last")
    .OrderBy(item => item)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("last", 1));
```

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: @rawanmansour yeah, I've updated the answer

Comment: you are sorting 2 times.

Comment: @AmitVerma no, the `.ThenBy()` criteria does not sort a 2nd time, it extends the `.OrderBy()` for items that are considered equal.

Comment: Then By Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order according to a key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0

Comment: @AmitVerma that's not exactly sorting two times, sorting two times means you go once over the list and then you go again over the same list. Subsequent sorting affects performance in a different way. If I do `.OrderBy().OrderBy()` then that is sorting two times, if I do a `.First()` on that I always get 2 sorts. With `.OrderBy().ThenBy()` the subsequent sort will be applied only on the 1st sub-sequence from `Orderby()` where items are considered equal. I get what you are saying, but it is not entirely accurate. You can double check this on reference source.

Comment: @Andrei15193 I am not saying going to same list again. I mean same thing which you are saying. IN this problem subsequent sort is not required.

Comment: @AmitVerma yes, that is true. For this problem there are better alternatives.

Comment: you don't need the ternary in your first example

`l.OrderBy(x => x.Equals("last", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ThenBy(x => x);`

Comment: @user2051770 the reason I went for ternary operator is because sorting boolean values can be unclear. I always wonder about the order of boolean values when sorting them while integer values are clear and are less confusing.

Comment: fair enough. going for clarity is never a bad thing

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Just realized the OP meant the value "last" and not the Last element. In this case, it would be much easier with

```
var result = l.OrderBy(x => string.Equals(x,"last")).ThenBy(x => x);
```

Please note the above would require sorting twice.You could also define a **Custom Comparer** to be used with `OrderBy`, and there by skipping multiple `OrderBy`

```
public class LastSkipComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private Func<T,bool> _selector;
    public LastSkipComparer(Func<T,bool> selector)
    {
        _selector = selector;
    }

    public int Compare(T instanceA, T instanceB)
    {
        if(_selector(instanceA)) return 1;
        if(_selector(instanceB)) return -1;
        return instanceA.CompareTo(instanceB);
    }
}
```

Now You could sort as,

```
var result = l.OrderBy(x=> x,
               new LastSkipComparer<string>((val)=> string.Equals(val,"last")));
```

Sample Output

[image]

### Initial Answer

To order every element, but the last, You could use use `SkipLast`, then Order the remaining, followed by Appending the Last Element again. For Example,

```
List<string> l = new[] {"z","u","last","b","a"}.ToList();
var result = l.SkipLast(1).OrderBy(x=>x).Append(l.Last());
```

[SkipLast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=net-5.0) : *Returns a new enumerable collection that contains the elements from source with the last count elements of the source collection omitted.*

[Enumerable.Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=net-5.0) : *Appends a value to the end of the sequence.*

Please note `SkipLast` require .NET(5.0, 6.0 Preview 3) Or .NET Core(   2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1) or .NET Standard 2.1

Sample Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<string> l = new List<string>{ "z", "u", "last", "b", "a" };

var k = l.Where(x=>x!="last").OrderBy(x=>x).Append("last");
```

Comment: There is no `.Append()`, you can use `.Concat()`, something like `l.Where(x=>x!="last").ToList().OrderBy(x=>x).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("last", 1))` or `l.Where(x=>x!="last").ToList().OrderBy(x=>x).Concat(new []{ "last" })`

Comment: check linq, there is append. this is working code.

Comment: @AmitVerma sorry but there is no .append

Comment: @rawanmansour https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=net-5.0

Comment: it means you are using older version. You need upgrade. Append is there.

Comment: @AmitVerma yep, it's in the newer versions, nice!